# Adding Foreground Service to Activity causes exception when calling onDestroy

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, service, android-lifecycle

I have a very simple foreground service which is as follows, it simply shows a foreground notification:

```
public class ForegroundLocationService extends Service {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.bullhorn_24dp);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Signed in")
                .setTicker("Signed into name123")
                .setContentText("You are broadcasting your location")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.broadcast_notifcation)
                .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                .setOngoing(true).build();

        startForeground(ServiceConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, notification);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can start this in my app by calling this in my activity:

```
Intent service = new Intent(this, ForegroundLocationService.class); 
startService(service);
```

This displays the following image, as expected:
[image: Example of emulator]

The issue is when I go to close my app via holding the phones home button and swiping the app closed. The activity’s onDestroy() method is called, but instead of leaving the foreground service running and closing the app, I get the following error (and the foreground service stops):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: uk.cal.codename.projectnedry, PID: 16495
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {uk/uk.CompanyScope.CompanyNavigationActivity.CompanyNavigationActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4203)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4221)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1538)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
   Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
      at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:427)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeInactive(FragmentManager.java:1662)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1452)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:2951)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:271)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:390)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:209)
      at uk.demo.genericmodelviewpresenter.GenericMvp.GenericMvpActivity.onDestroy(GenericMvpActivity.java:100)
      at uk.CompanyScope.CompanyNavigationActivity.CompanyNavigationActivity.onDestroy(CompanyNavigationActivity.java:533)
      at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6881)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1153)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4190)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4221) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1538) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

The lines where the error occurs are as follows:

CompanyNavigationActivity.java:533 ‘super.onDestroy();’

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    getSpecificImpOfGenericPresenter().closeRealm();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

GenericMvpActivity.java:100 ‘super.onDestroy();’

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //Unbind Butterknife bindings
    if(mUnbinder!=null) {
        mUnbinder.unbind();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And then it goes off into Android fragment classes. I’m at a loss as to why this foreground service would cause an issue with the lifecycle of the Activity it is launched in. If I comment out the call to start the service, everything runs as normal.

Any ideas as to how the service is affecting the Activity in this way?

**EDIT 1**

I have the service listed in my manifest as:

```
<service android:name=".LocationService.ForegroundLocationService"
    android:icon="@drawable/bullhorn_24dp"
    android:label="Assemble sharing">
</service>
```

**EDIT 2**

Presenters closeRealm method is below, however commenting this out in the Activity's onDestroy method gives the same error.

```
public void closeRealm() {
    this.mRealmDatabase.getInstance().removeAllChangeListeners();
    this.mRealmDatabase.close();
}
```

Comment: show getSpecificImpOfGenericPresenter().closeRealm(); method

Comment: @TimCastelijns added in edit 2

Comment: Yes, mRealmDatabase is a Realm instance

Comment: Do you use fragments?

Comment: I do, but at this moment none have been created. I have a button that instantiates a viewpager containing 4 fragments. When the fragments are instantiated, this error does not occur.

Comment: @Calco according to stacktrace something goes wrong with fragments. Look at this line android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeInactive(FragmentManager.java:1662), manager tries to set null at fragment position in active fragments list. Also fragment is not null at this line (You would have NPE if it is null). Maybe onDestroy is called twice.

Comment: @Calco Or you use fragments in a wrong way.

Comment: Debugging through I don't seem to hit onDestroy twice, it just super calls up the superclasses until it hits the fragment error and crashes.